# Tiptap v2 (Prosemirror) with NextJS

Tags: regex, typescript, next.js, pagination, tiptap

This is my first time writing here, on Stack Overflow, and I am asking for your help in coming to grips with a problem.

The problem I'm going to submit to you is related to the development of the MVP of my new startup that deals with developing SaaS for the creative industry. The MVP in question is a text editor for writing screenplays and I am having a problem.

If you don't know a screenplay has a number of features including the scene title is made like this: "1. EXT. PUB - NIGHT"

Keeping in mind that I was able to do the following:

- make each paragraph autonomous,
- create a function that automatically detects the format based on a set of keywords,
- when the algorithm is active make all text in the paragraph uppercase;

```
import { Extension } from '@tiptap/core';
import { Plugin } from 'prosemirror-state';
import { Fragment } from 'prosemirror-model';

let paragraphCount = 0; // Variable to track paragraph count

const SceneTitle = Extension.create({
    name: 'SceneTitle',

    addProseMirrorPlugins() {
        return [
            new Plugin({
                appendTransaction: (_, oldState, newState) => {
                    let tr = newState.tr;
                    let oldParagraphCount = 0;
                    let newParagraphCount = 0;

                    const regex = /^(INT\.|EXT\.|int\.|ext\.|INT|EXT|int|ext|EST|EST\.|est|est\.)/;

                    oldState.doc.descendants((node) => {
                        if (node.type.name === 'paragraph') {
                            oldParagraphCount++;
                        }
                    });

                    newState.doc.descendants((node, pos) => {
                        if (node.type.name === 'paragraph') {
                            newParagraphCount++;
                            if (regex.test(node.textContent)) {
                                let from = pos + 1;
                                let to = from + node.textContent.length;
                                let fragment = Fragment.from(newState.schema.text(node.textContent.toUpperCase()));
                                tr.replaceWith(from, to, fragment);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if (newParagraphCount > oldParagraphCount) {
                        paragraphCount++;
                        console.log(`Paragraph inserted. Total paragraphs: ${paragraphCount}`); // Print paragraph count
                    } else if (newParagraphCount < oldParagraphCount) {
                        paragraphCount = 0;
                        console.log(`Paragraphs deleted. Paragraph count reset to zero.`); // Print paragraph count reset
                    }

                    return tr;
                },
            }),
        ];
    },
});

export default SceneTitle;
```

Next, when I enter the numbering of the scene titles it happens that through the creation of an index I am able to divide the paragraph into three parts, namely: the numbering, the text that contains the keyword and the rest of the text. Only when I go to write the keyword, as "Int" it happens that it makes me capitalize only the keyword and not also the text that follows it, however that has not been written yet, if instead I write first the text that will go after the keyword and then write the keyword, as "Int" it makes me uppercase everything.

```
import { Extension } from '@tiptap/core';
import { Plugin } from 'prosemirror-state';
import { Fragment } from 'prosemirror-model';

let paragraphCount = 0; // Variable to keep track of paragraph count
let sceneCount = 1; // Variable to track scene count
let appliedPositions = new Set(); // Together to track applied positions

const SceneTitle = Extension.create({
    name: 'SceneTitle',

    addProseMirrorPlugins() {
        return [
            new Plugin({
                appendTransaction: (_, oldState, newState) => {
                    let tr = newState.tr;
                    let oldParagraphCount = 0;
                    let newParagraphCount = 0;

                    const regex = /^(INT\.|EXT\.|int\.|ext\.|INT|EXT|int|ext|EST|EST\.|est|est\.)/;

                    oldState.doc.descendants((node) => {
                        if (node.type.name === 'paragraph') {
                            oldParagraphCount++;
                        }
                    });

                    newState.doc.descendants((node, pos) => {
                        if (node.type.name === 'paragraph' && regex.test(node.textContent)) {
                            if (!appliedPositions.has(pos)) {
                                let from = pos + 1;
                                let to = from + node.textContent.length;
                                let fragment = Fragment.from(newState.schema.text(sceneCount + "." + " " + node.textContent.toUpperCase() + "." + " "));
                                tr.replaceWith(from, to, fragment);
                                appliedPositions.add(pos);
                                sceneCount++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (node.type.name === 'paragraph') {
                            newParagraphCount++;
                        }
                    });

                    if (newParagraphCount > oldParagraphCount) {
                        paragraphCount++;
                        console.log(`Paragraph inserted. Total paragraphs: ${paragraphCount}`); // Print paragraph count
                    } else if (newParagraphCount < oldParagraphCount) {
                        paragraphCount = 0;
                        sceneCount = 1; // Resets scene count only when paragraphs are deleted
                        appliedPositions.clear();
                        console.log(`Paragraphs deleted. Paragraph and scene count reset to zero.`); // Print paragraph and scene count reset
                    }

                    return tr;
                },
            }),
        ];
    },
});

export default SceneTitle;
```

Now I can't figure out how to make the scene title have progressive numbering, that it doesn't loop, and that all the text in that paragraph is uppercase.

The other problem I ran into is that simulating what potentially a user will be able to do, remember they are screenwriters, filmmakers and videomakers, is to go and insert a new scene title above the existing one only I was able to get it to update but not properly, that is, the new title had the sequence number following the last paragraph created, so:

- First example of incorrect numbering.:

> "1. INT. ..."
> "1. EXT. ..."
> "2. INT. ..."
> "3. EXT. ..."

- Second example of incorrect numbering.:

> "4. INT. ..."
> "1. EXT. ..."
> "2. INT. ..."
> "3. EXT. ..."

The technology stack I am using is as below:

- NextJS v14.1.0,
- TailwindCSS,
- TipTap v2,
- Typescript,
- NodeJS v20.8.0

Below are a couple of examples of what it should look like:

- First example of how the scene title should be numbered:

> 1. INT. PUB - NIGHT

- Example of what the numbered sequence with various scene titles should look like:

> 1. INT. PUB - NIGHT
>    We reveal that SHAUN is sitting with a woman, LIZ. They are
>    both in their late twenties. LIZ looks slightly concerned,
>    SHAUN looks slightly confused. They are having a drink.
> 2. INT. APARTMENT COMPLEX - MORNING
> 3. INT. APARTMENT - MORNING
> 4. INT. LIVING ROOM - MORNING

Comment: Telling the whole story is not needed. Just explain the problem, only show the minimal amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem. Please read about [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I appreciate the advice about providing a minimal, reproducible example. My intention was not to tell a complete story, but to provide sufficient context for my problem. I will endeavor to focus more on the technical details and specific code needed to illustrate my question.

Comment: Please replace your images by [blocks of raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Also explain what your software does (use case more than the programming part), what the input should be like, with some valid examples and what your software should output. This would help us give you a hand to solve your problem. Typically, your regex seems complicated and can be written in a better way, but we should know more clearly what you are trying to do. An example of regex, but without knowing what's your intension: https://regex101.com/r/xXkwiu/1

Comment: @PatrickJanser I've updated the question I asked, I hope it's better now than before!

Anyway, the software is a text editor for screenwriters, to put it simply an enhanced Word for screenwriters. The difference with other existing solutions is that the user experience has been rethought to make it less cumbersome.

Comment: @PatrickJanser That said, the goal is to have the scene title that is activated when a keyword is typed such as: "INT.", "EXT.", "int.", "ext.", "INT", "EXT", "int", "ext", "EST", "EST.", "est" and/or "est." and that does three things primarily, namely:
1. Add progressive numbering to each scene title created, this also means that if I go over an existing paragraph and create another one, the numbering should update,
2. That all the text, that of the keywords and what you are going to put after, so for example; "PUB - NIGHT" be uppercase,

Comment: @PatrickJanser

3. That when creating a scene title you add a blank space before and after the paragraph that undergoes the update, although this is not required.

Comment: Why not just [detecting text starting with `INT`, `EXT` or `EST`](https://regex101.com/r/xXkwiu/2), case-insensitive, optionally followed by a dot and then convert the paragraph to a `<h2>` tag? You'll then be able to use [CSS counters](https://nikitahl.com/numbered-headings-with-css-counter) to have the numbered list always up to date, without having to program anything.

Comment: @PatrickJanser At the beginning of when I started writing the code that was the idea, however it did not convert the <p> tag to <h2>. As far as inserting keywords that way I was excluding all possibilities also because sometimes the uppercase would only convert it for me if I inserted the period at the end, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done some *NextJS* before, but I'll just give you some
hints with a minimal vanilla JS example that you then can implement
yourself in your app.

#### Step 1: the regular expression

As I mentioned in my comments, your regular expression should
be rewritten to handle all your inputs. I've done it by
handling:

- An optional number with or without a dot. This one may be
  wrong, as you mentioned, so we'll just drop it.
- A type of place (`INT`, `EXT` or `EST`), with an optional
  dot, and case-insensitive, in order to match "*INT*", "*Int*"
  or "*int*", etc.
- The place name (ex: "*Bedroom*").
- The hyphen separator, with mandatory spaces around.
- When it is (ex: "*morning*").

Based on the regex I posted by comment, with the additional
handling of an eventual undesired number at the beginning:

```
/^(\d+\.?\s*)?(?<place_type>int|ext|est)\.?\s*(?<place>.*?)\s+-\s+(?<when>.*?)\s*$/i
```

As you see, I use named groups because I found them easier than
indexed groups, especially if you change the regex later. Group
names don't change, but indexed groups do.

Test it here with the details: https://regex101.com/r/qDPvYK/1

#### Step 2: converting paragraphs to headings

As I also mentioned in my comment, it may be far simpler to not
count the title yourself and just do it with CSS counters.

Titles should not stay paragraphs. Why? For semantic reasons.
A search engine will also be able to understand the content in
a far better way.

You said you didn't manage to convert a paragraph into a heading.
Yes, you are right. But with a bit of googling, you'll quickly
find that you just have to create a new `<h2>` tag and put it
instead of the `<p>` tag. This can be done in a lot of ways. The
simplest I found is to get the parent node and then use the
`.replaceChild()` method.

I've added a button to the HTML demo so that you can see the
content before and after running the conversion algorithm.

For the uppercase feature, it's up to you to decide. Either do
it at rendering with a CSS `text-transform` rule or do it by
calling the `.toUpperCase()` in the JS. I prefer doing it with CSS
because I think that something such as "*Hard Rock Cafe*"
should stay as it is, respecting it's own case, but can be
displayed "*HARD ROCK CAFE*" graphically. The advantage
is that you could change that CSS in the future without loosing
the original case.

```js
const regexTitle = /^(\d+\.?\s*)?(?<place_type>int|ext|est)\.?\s*(?<place>.*?)\s+-\s+(?<when>.*?)\s*$/gmi;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    function convertToTitles() {
    // Loop over all paragraphs to try and convert some to headings.
    document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((p, i) => {
      const match = regexTitle.exec(p.innerText);

      if (match) {
        const placeType = match.groups.place_type.toUpperCase(),
              place = match.groups.place,
              when = match.groups.when;

        const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerText = placeType + '. ' + place + ' - ' + when;
        p.parentNode.replaceChild(h2, p);
      }
    });
  }
  
  const convertButton = document.getElementById('convert-to-titles');
  
  convertButton.addEventListener('click', convertToTitles);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  padding: 2em;
}

.scenario {
  min-width: 15em;
  max-width: 30em;
  background: white;
  /* More padding on the left to pull out the scene title number. */
  padding: 2em 2em 2em 4em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-family: "Courrier New", Courrier, monospace;
  counter-reset: scene-title-nbr;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0 .5em 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative; /* For absolute ::before pseudo-element. */
}

h2::before {
  content: counter(scene-title-nbr);
  counter-increment: scene-title-nbr;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<article class="scenario">
  <header>
    <h1>Scenario</h1>
  </header>
  
  <p>INT. Pub - night</p>
  <p>
    We reveal that SHAUN is sitting with a woman, LIZ. They are both in their
    late twenties. LIZ looks slightly concerned, SHAUN looks slightly confused.
    They are having a drink.
  </p>

  <p>INT. Apartment complex - morning</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi
    maxime quisquam itaque numquam quas tempore quo, ex reprehenderit
    ea dicta sequi voluptatem ipsum id cupiditate autem perspiciatis
    obcaecati consectetur quod.
  </p>

  <p>1. INT. Apartment - morning</p>
  <p>
    Text should come here...
  </p>

  <p>INT. Living room - morning</p>
  <p>
    Text should come here...
  </p>

  <p>3. Ext Swimming-pool - midday</p>
  <p>SHAUN dives into the pool while LIZ is sunbathing...</p>
</article>

<button id="convert-to-titles">Convert to titles</button>
```

The code can be improved when you create the title. Typically,
it would be logical to have something like this, where the several
fields of information in the title are split into sub tags:

```css
.scenario {
  font-family: "Courrier New", Courrier, monospace;
  counter-reset: scene-title-nbr;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

h2::before {
  content: counter(scene-title-nbr);
  counter-increment: scene-title-nbr;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em;
}

.scene-title {
  line-height: 1.4; /* Just to fix the clock emoji. */
}

.scene-title abbr.place-type {
  text-decoration: none; /* override defaults */
}
.scene-title abbr.place-type:hover {
  text-decoration: underline dotted silver; /* Show it on hover */
}

time[datetime="14:00"]::after {
  content: " ";
}
time[datetime="20:00"]::after {
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<article class="scenario">

  <h2 class="scene-title">
    <abbr class="place-type" title="Interior">INT</abbr>
    <span class="place-name">Bedroom</span>
    <span class="separator">-</span>
    <time class="when" datetime="20:00">evening</time>
  </h2>

  <p>Some text...</p>
  
  <h2 class="scene-title">
    <abbr class="place-type" title="Exterior">EXT</abbr>
    <span class="place-name">Swimming pool</span>
    <span class="separator">-</span>
    <time class="when" datetime="14:00">afternoon</time>
  </h2>
  
  <p>Some more text...</p>

</article>
```

Comment: Good evening @PatrickJanser, thank you very much for your feedback, I am integrating your solution inside my code and it seems to work by fixing a little something, for example it still gives me the numbered sequence that always has "1" as the number. Having said that thank you very much for your help!